# Magento block custom plugin

Tags: php, plugins, magento2

I have problem with because third-party module has plugin aroundGetMediaAttributes on class Magento\Framework\Config\View with sortOrder=10. This plugin modify image size. I need block this plugin and return result from core function but I do not know how to do it.
In addition i need block custom plugin only in some cases, not always.
I created second plugin aroundGetMediaAttributes with higher sortOrder and return result from callable but still have wrong imagesize.
How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you can disable plugin by name :

```
<type name="Vendor\Module\Path\To\Class">
    <plugin name="plugin_name" disabled="true" />
</type>
```